# 3D anatomy software

Tags: 3d

I would like to find a software to have a restricted 3D view of human body anatomy.
Instead of reinventing the wheel, I would like to know if such a thing already exists.

Hopefully, it would:

- Have a filter view to show only skeleton + muscles such as in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JE67Wp-zsc (I find the channel very good by the way!)
- Allow body motion so that I can turn the body easily for example or imply a motion of a body member and the related muscles tensions and shapes are adapted accordingly and automatically.
- Allow customization such as muscle highlighting with a different color, annotation etc.
- Target a PC preferably, with Windows or Linux

As far as I know, that's not simple nor automatic to do such a thing. In the free university project of the video, there is no mention of what software has been used. Thus, I would suspect there is no out-of-the-box software to do that, but if you have heard of one, please share!

If that doesn't exist, is there any open-source project I could start from to do that?

Notes:

- I could adapt to a different target if the tool is fine.
- Please feel free to answer even if it is a mobile app (as I said, target is not a hard constraint).

Answer (score 3):

There is an Open Source project that has made a start on exactly what you are looking for within the [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) 3D modelling tool kit.

You can read about the muscle simulator, (so far), [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?342143-Blender-2-71-NEW-Muscle-Simulator).

[image]

Blender itself is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source & Cross Platform
- Offers full photo-realistic rendering
- Can produce animations & [movies](http://archive.blender.org/features-gallery/movies/)
- Has a physics engine and a game engine
- Has multiple simulations engines
- Includes movie editing
- 100s of other [features](https://www.blender.org/features/)

If nothing else it gives you a good starting point and the possibility of enhancing it with others.

Answer (score 2):

Per your request, the mobile app I referred to is called [Essential Anatomy 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KDEVVDI) by [3D4Medical.com, LLC](http://completeanatomy.3d4medical.com/).

[image]

It’s highly rated (4.3/5.0 on Amazon), inexpensive ($10 US) and provides these **features**…

- New 3D technology via 3D4Medical's latest graphics engine
- Over 4,000 highly detailed anatomical structures
- Multiple Selection Mode. Hide/Fade/Isolate individual or multiple
  structures
- Preset and customizable Bookmarks
- Correct audio pronunciation for every structure
- Latin nomenclature for each anatomical structure
- User friendly and intuitive interface
- Multiple search options
- Dynamic quiz function - Drag and Drop and Multi-choice
- Custom search modes
- Extensive social media tools and sharing capability

**It includes the anatomy for these systems**...

- Skeletal
- Muscles
- Connective Tissue
- Veins
- Arteries
- Nerves
- Respiratory
- Digestive
- Urinary
- Lymphatic
- also includes the Brain and Heart

I use the mobile version, but, after a bit more research, I found that it’s available on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1):

## [Anatomy 360](http://www.anatomy360.info/)

[image]

It is a very user friendly 3D anatomy modelling software still in development. They provide an online demo with the following features:

- Full Pan, Rotation and Zoom control using only left and right mouse buttons with Key presses
- Spec and Diffuse sliders
- Texture on off switch
- Background brightness slider
- Flat Shaded Mode
- Black and white mode
- Rim light brightness and angle sliders
- Spot / Directional light switch
- Ambient intensity slider
- Field of view slider
- New control system
- Tone mapping switch
- Vignette switch
- Floor on and off switch